XSLT: Code wont run in notepad++ due to xsdate or current-date()
I have an xml code that displays the contract details of an employee.
I need to only display contracts that are indefinite(Does not have an end date) and contract that have not ended(the end date is greater than the current date). The code runs on some platforms but not notepad++
I have the following XML code,
<peci:Employee_Contract>
    <peci:Contract_Type>Fixed-term</peci:Contract_Type>
    <peci:End_Date>20190930</peci:End_Date>
</peci:Employee_Contract>
<peci:Employee_Contract>
    <peci:Contract_Type>Fixed-term</peci:Contract_Type>
    <peci:End_Date>20240930</peci:End_Date>
</peci:Employee_Contract>
    <peci:Employee_Contract>
    <peci:Contract_Type>Fixed-term</peci:Contract_Type>
    <peci:End_Date>20260930</peci:End_Date>
</peci:Employee_Contract>
    <peci:Employee_Contract>
    <peci:Contract_Type>Fixed-term</peci:Contract_Type>
    <peci:End_Date>20240620</peci:End_Date>
</peci:Employee_Contract>
    <peci:Employee_Contract>
    <peci:Contract_Type>Indefinite</peci:Contract_Type>
    </peci:Employee_Contract>

I need to only display jobs that are indefinite(Does not have an end date) and jobs where the end date is greater than the current date.
This is the XSLT code I have so far.
<xsl:variable name="dateM" select="current-date()"/>
<xsl:template match="peci:Workers_Effective_Stack/peci:Worker/peci:Effective_Change/peci:Employee_Contract">
    <xsl:if test="(((not(peci:End_Date)) or((xs:date(concat(substring(peci:End_Date,1,4),'-',substring(peci:End_Date,5,2),'-',substring(peci:End_Date,7,2)))) &gt; $dateM))) ">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

I was able to get the expected result(below) in 'http://xsltransform.net/gWmuiJ1' but the same code wont run in Notepad++ or even 'https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog_choose'. Am I missing something?
        <peci:Contract_Type>Fixed-term</peci:Contract_Type>
        <peci:End_Date>20240930</peci:End_Date>
     </peci:Employee_Contract>
     <peci:Employee_Contract>
        <peci:Contract_Type>Fixed-term</peci:Contract_Type>
        <peci:End_Date>20260930</peci:End_Date>
     </peci:Employee_Contract>
     <peci:Employee_Contract>
        <peci:Contract_Type>Indefinite</peci:Contract_Type>
     </peci:Employee_Contract>


Well, to run XSLT 2 you need an XSLT 2 or 3 processor like Saxon (exists as Saxon HE Java, SaxonC, Saxon HE .NET, SaxonJs/xslt3 for JavaScript/Node.js). I don't think Notepad++ has an XSLT processor built in and the existing XML tools plugin uses Microsoft's MSXML, an XSLT 1.0 processor. So you will need to install some XSLT 2 (or these days as XSLT 3 is the currently supported version) XSLT 3 processor and run it from a command tool/shell.

How do I change the code so that I can run it though notepad++

There are a lots of ways to run XSLT 3, you can do it online at several sites I have created, for instance, e.g. https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddle/, https://xsltfiddle-beta.liberty-development.net/, https://saxonc-xmlworkbench.azurewebsites.net/. There a plugins to run XSLT 3 with Saxon HE Java and/or SaxonJS/xslt3 for Visual Studio code. For Notepad++, as I said, install a command line version of an XSLT 2 or 3 processor and run it as a Notepad++ command or perhaps as an NppExec command. To change the code to use XSLT 1 with MSXML is not possible for lack of XPath 2/3 support.

Notepad++, like most Microsoft software, only supports the ancient XSLT 1.0 standard and you need at least XSLT 2.0. As Martin explains in comments, you can continue to use Nodepad++ purely as an editor but run an XSLT 2.0+ processor from the command line, or you can switch to a more modern XML development environment such as Oxygen.

Notepad++ is not Microsoft software. It allows writing plugins in various programming languages like C++ or C# and its XML Tools plugin implemented in C/C++ currently uses MSXML for XSLT (1.0), though I think it uses libxslt in earlier versions.

The XMLTools plugin uses MSXML, Microsoft's trusted but ancient and never updated XSLT 1.0 processor for XSLT. See https://github.com/morbac/xmltools/issues/215#issuecomment-2527883394 for a download of a prototype of a replacement of XMLTools that, with the help of SaxonC 12 HE, then offers a XMLTools menu option to run XSLT 3.
